# How to specify the view controller classes to be used by UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

In interface builder I select the Tab Bar Controller item. The inspector shows me a list of associated view controllers. For any strange reason, I can not define anywhere the exact name for an view controller. I have an DetailsViewController and an SetupViewController. However, I can only select generic names such as "Navigation View controller" and this kind of stuff. But I can't put these exact view controllers there.

I also created two View Controller items and associated these with the appropriate classes. Anyways, no way to hook these up with the tabs. What's the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the class of an object in Interface Builder by changing the class name in the Identity tab of the inspector.

[alt text http://grab.by/1YQ6](http://grab.by/1YQ6)